# windows batch syntax error in a not used if block

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line-arguments

why the following batch script is failing with "The syntax of the command is incorrect." error on Windows 7 if I provide no argument:

```
IF NOT [%1]==[] (
echo "blablabla" > %1
) ELSE (
echo "please provide argument"
)
```

But there is no problem with this code:

```
IF NOT [%1]==[] (
echo "blablabla"
) ELSE (
echo "printing not existing argument: %1"
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The redirect to nothing > in the first echo is the problem. You must specify a redirection destination.

Comment: Yes but redirect nothing is in a conditional block which won't be executed.. anyway I found a workaround:
IF NOT [%1]==[] (
SET path=%1
echo "blablabla" > %path%

Comment: @gOldie_E36, this won't work: 1) you'd need delayed expansion, but I'm pretty sure that does not work with the redirection targets; 2) do *not* change system variable `path`;

Comment: delayed expansion is an other good solution, thanks. weird windows stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the entire `if`/`else` block is read and parsed at once. So if `%1` is empty, the redirection `>`  is still parsed and evaluated invalid.

You can work around the issue like that:

```
if not "%~1"=="" (
  goto :Redirect
) else (
  echo please provide argument
)
goto :Continue
:Redirect
> "%~1" echo blablabla
:Continue
```

I replaced the brackets by quotation marks, because they protect white-spaces and other special characters. The `~`-symbol ensures that the returned argument appears unquoted, so there is always one pair of quotes in the expression `"%~1"`.

Moreover, I removed quotes from the `echo` command lines as they were output too, and I moved the redirection part `> "%~1"` in front of `echo` in order to avoid a trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to be returned.

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulating the filename by double quotations enforces the `if/else` block to parse and read the expression correctly.

For example

```
IF NOT [%1]==[] (
echo "blablabla" > "%1"
) ELSE (
echo "please provide argument"
)
```